# AWS Lambda Python S3 Read File Error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, amazon-iam

Trying to read a file from a bucket in s3.  The bucket has a trigger wired to a python lambda function.  This then runs when a new file is put in the bucket.  I keep getting an error.

This the code:

## Download the file from S3 to the local filesystem

```
try:
    s3.meta.client.download_file(bucket, key, localFilename)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.'.format(key, bucket))
    raise e
```

I get this error

'ClientMeta' object has no attribute 'client'

I am thinking it could be the IAM but the Lambda function has the AWSLambdaFullAccess Role which is pretty much an admin in S3.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: It looks to me as if `s3.meta` doesn't have the `client` object, so the call above is failing before even getting to AWS.  I'm guessing the exception is an `AttributeError`?  Please edit your question to include where the variable `s3` gets its value from.  Please also include the full traceback.

Comment: Why don't you use boto3 s3 low level client to download the file. `import boto3

# Get the service client
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# Download object at bucket-name with key-name to tmp.txt
s3.download_file("bucket-name", "key-name", "tmp.txt")`  .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is caused by creating a boto3 **client** instead of **resource**.

Example (this will reproduce your error):

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.meta.client.download_file(bucket, key, localFilename)
```

You have two solutions:

1) Change to use the "**high-level abstracted**" s3 resource:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.download_file(bucket, key, localFilename)
```

2) Directly use the "**low-level**" s3 client download_file()

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.download_file(bucket, key, localFilename)
```

[Working with Boto3 Low-Level Clients](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/clients.html)

Comment: that fixed it.  Thanks John.

Answer (score 0):

I think may be refer incorrectly object type for variable `s3`. `s3.meta.client` may be something you use when `s3` is `ResourceMeta` object, but here I think `s3` is `Client` object.

So you can just write

`try:
    s3.download_file(bucket, key, localFilename)
except Exception as e:
    ...`